# pyqt5 getting the ID of selected item of combobox in database

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

i have populated a combo box from my database, also i want to have my database connected to the combobox backward, i mean i need to know  the id of the customer selected in my example to have account balance, i dont know what shall i do, here is the part i have populated my combobox from db:

```
def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "-- SELECT --"))

        # ''' START SQL UPDATE COMBO BOX BY CUSTOMER NAMES'''
        connection = sqlite3.connect("./my-database.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        sql = """
            SELECT * FROM customer
        """
        cursor.execute(sql)
        combo_counter = 0
        for names in cursor:
            combo_counter += 1
            self.comboBox.setItemText(combo_counter, _translate("MainWindow", str(names[1])))
            current_j_date
        connection.commit()
        connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this comboBox a QComboBox? If it is, you can use *currentData* to store *id of the customer* (or even customer instance if you prefer).

Here is how you add rows in QComboBox:

```
for customer_row in cursor.execute(load_custormer_statement):
    self.comboBox.addItem(customer_row['name'], userData=customer_row['id'])
```

How to response to user selection?

```
# connect slot to user selection signal
self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_customer_selected)
```

```
def on_customer_selected(self, _):
    customer_id = self.comboxBox.currentData()
    # do what you want with customer id
```

Comment: i think you misunderstood or i didnt get your answer, i want a connection between them, is that this?

Comment: It is a connection between user selection and code execution with customer id. If it is not what you mean by "connection",  you need to make it clear.